# how to decompose a nested list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a nested list and want to decompose it, exactly inverse of merging.
suppose i have list bellow:

```
f=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

I am trying to obtain :

```
a1=[1,1,1,1]
a2=[2,2,2,2]
a3=[3,3,3,3]
```

I have tried this command:

```
a1=f[:][0:1]
a2=f[:][1:2]
a3=f[:][2:3]
```

but it does not work right. do you know my wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may do so like the following:

```
a = [list(i) for i in zip(*f)]
```

Now:

`a[0]` will be `[1, 1, 1, 1]`

`a[1]` will be `[2, 2, 2, 2]`

`a[2]` will be `[3, 3, 3, 3]`

Comment: Glad you liked it.

Comment: thank you, , i did it. sorry i was not familiar with it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
f=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

for i in zip(*f):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list and it return iterator of tuples.

Using [map()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) to apply `list` on the iterator of tuples that we are getting from `zip` and it return an iterator. And then passing the iterator to [list()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-list).

```
a = list(map(list, zip(*f)))
```

Or

```
a = []
for i in iter(map(list, zip(*f))):
    a.append(i)
```

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score -1):

What you should do in here is to use a `for` loop.

```
f=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
a1=[x[0] for x in f]
a2=[x[1] for x in f]
a3=[x[2] for x in f]
print(a1,a2,a3)

>>>[1, 1, 1, 1] [2, 2, 2, 2] [3, 3, 3, 3]
```